# Are token creatures considerd as a creature spell?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Are token creatures considerd creature spells? For instince when I use [Drana's Chosen](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDrana%27s%5d%2b%5bChosen%5d) tap effect combined with [Zendikar Resurgent](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bZendikar%20Resurgent%5d) would it allow me to draw a card?

Answer (score 4):

No.

A creature token IS a creature, but that has nothing to do with your combo in this case. Tapping Drana's Chosen is activating an ability, it is not casting a spell. These are two completely different things.

If Zendikar Resurgent triggered on "whenever a creature enters the battlefield" instead, then a creature token entering would count.

The title of your question shows that you have mixed up two very different concepts: a creature spell (or, creature card on the stack) and a creature are not the same thing. A spell exists only on the stack, while a creature is a permanent that exists only on the battlefield. So a token, which can be a creature, can't be a spell. A spell could create tokens, but that doesn't mean that a spell can be a token or a creature.